# How to determine what form was closed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I'm sure there is some event but I've never had to use this before but I'm just looking for some way to check which form was hidden/closed and do some function based on what window was actually closed or hidden.

So when the application starts up, there will be buttons, each open a new window. Once processing is done on those windows, they will be hidden and focus will return to the original window, is there a way to tell what window was hidden as focus returns to the main window?

Comment: form closed/form closing Events? this is at every form. as @Crono said  where do you need to know your form was closed?

Comment: So when the application starts up, there will be buttons, each open a new window.  Once processing is done on those windows, they will be hidden and focus will return to the original window, is there a way to tell what window was hidden as focus returns to the main window?

Comment: The Form class always fires its FormClosed event after it was closed.  Subscribing the event is up to you, there is no Application.FormClosed event.

Comment: Why not just use modal forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach event handlers to each form you create:

```
AddHandler form.FormClosed, AddressOf SomeMethodThatHandlesFormClosed
```

This method will require that you have two parameters, one of type `Object` and one of type `FormClosedEventArgs`. Typically they're named `sender` and `e`, respectively:

```
Sub SomeMethodThatHandlesFormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs )
    ' sender parameter represents the closed form instance.
    Dim form As Form = sender

    ' do what you have to do with the closed form here.
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Reading your question again I notice you mention *hiding* the forms, which is different from *closing*. In this case you might want to handle the `VisibleChanged` event instead:

```
AddHandler form.FormClosed, AddressOf SomeMethodThatHandlesVisibleChanged

' ...

Sub SomeMethodThatHandlesVisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs )
    ' sender parameter represents the hidden form instance.
    Dim form As Form = sender

    If Not form.Visible Then
        ' do what you have to do with the hiding form here.
    End If
End Sub
```